# Record Video with Audio in Raspberry Pi using USB Cam

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, video-capture, audio-recording

How to record video with audio in Raspberry Pi using USB Cam that has built-in microphone.
I was able to do it separately, but I need to do them together.
I need a python code. This the code that I use it to record the video only:

```
def video_capture():
    global RS
    print 'try recording'
    global end_time
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

    if end_time is None:
                    end_time = time.time()
    while True:
        while RS == 1:
            while time.time() - end_time >= 1:
                end_rec = time.time() + 20
                print 'writing video'
                t_start = time.time()
                while t_start < end_rec:
                    date_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
                    out = cv2.VideoWriter(str(date_string)+'.avi',fourcc, 13, (640,480))
                    while (camera.isOpened()) & (time.time() < end_rec):
                        ret, frame3 = camera.read()
                        if ret==True:
                            out.write(frame3)
                    end_time = time.time()
                    break
                print 'The End'
```